# sql select a field into 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

I am trying to run below 2 queries on the same table and hoping to get results in 2 different columns.

Query 1: `select ID as M from table where field = 1`
returns:

```
1
2
3
```

Query 2: `select ID as N from table where field = 2` 
returns:

```
4
5
6
```

My goal is to get

```
Column1 - Column2
-----------------
1            4
2            5
3            6
```

Any suggestions? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks

Comment: SQL result sets are inherently unordered *unless* you use an `order by` clause.  There is no concept of "first" or "second" row.  How are the two result sets ordered?

Comment: The order by clause can be in a windowing function such as ROW_NUMBER.  Just not limited to the final ORDER BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a primary key to foreign key relationship to JOIN data between two tables.

That is the idea about relational algebra and normalization.  Otherwise, the correlation of the data is meaningless.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

The CROSS JOIN will give you all possibilities.  (1,4), (1,5), (1, 6) ... (3,6).  I do not think that is what you want.

You can always use a ROW_NUMBER() OVER () function to generate a surrogate key in both tables.  Order the data the way you want inside the OVER () clause.  However, this is still not in any Normal form.

**In short. Why do this?**

Quick test database.  Stores products from sporting goods and home goods using non-normal form.

The results of the SELECT do not mean anything.

```
-- Just play
use tempdb;
go

-- Drop table
if object_id('abnormal_form') > 0
drop table abnormal_form
go

-- Create table
create table abnormal_form
(
    Id int,
    Category int,
    Name varchar(50)
);

-- Load store products
insert into abnormal_form values
(1, 1, 'Bike'),
(2, 1, 'Bat'),
(3, 1, 'Ball'),
(4, 2, 'Pot'),
(5, 2, 'Pan'),
(6, 2, 'Spoon');

-- Sporting Goods
select * from abnormal_form where Category = 1

-- Home Goods
select * from abnormal_form where Category = 2

-- Does not mean anything to me
select Id1, Id2 from
(select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Rid1, Id as Id1 
 from abnormal_form where Category = 1) as s
join
(select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Rid2, Id as Id2 
 from abnormal_form where Category = 2) as h
on s.Rid1 = h.Rid2
```

We definitely need more information from the user.

[image]

Comment: OP uses just one (single) table - see the very first sentence of his post.

Comment: If it is just one table, SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1.  The relationship is in the tuple or record.

Comment: **WRONG**. Read the post.

Comment: You are right, I will re-post.  Again, why?  Obviously not normal form.  One table, one type of data, one key ...

Comment: Until OP answers the crucial question that `Gordon Linoff` asked, it seems to be pointless to guess what OP really needs.

Comment: As mentioned we are trying to read from the same column the only difference is the where clause.

Comment: @user3006102 Check out join with sub-queries.  It will do what you want assuming order by ID is correct, still do not know the business logic.  Good luck.

Comment: I think you will need `FULL OUTER JOIN` to cover cases where Categories have different amount of rows.

Comment: @PM77-1 The outer join will introduce NULLS into the equation.  But again, there is no clear business logic.