# stored procedure that returns in one row duplicate column names and converts 1->N to a string

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to put all the below in a single stored procedute that returns a single row because the data is up on Sql Azure and the rule for it is do everything in a single query with a single return.

I have the following tables:

```
Person (
    PersonId
    FirstName
    ...
)
CompanyDomains (
    CompanyId
    EmailDomain
)
Company (
    CompanyId
    CompanyName
    Billing_PersonId
    Admin_PersonId
    ...
)
```

I have two problems here. The first is I want to get all the elements of a Company row, and the 2 Person rows of data. That's easy with a join. But the columns for the 2 person columns will have duplicate names. I can do 'as' one by one, which is a pain as the database schema is still in a state of flux. Is there a global way to apply 'as' so all the columns brought in from Billing_PersonId get a Billing_ prepended to the column name and Admin_ prepended to the admin column name?

The second is there is a 1->N list of company domains. Is there a way to pull all those and add a column that is a single string that has "domain1;domain2;" in it? We have the distinct domains in the CompanyDomain table so we can quickly find the company that owns any domain. But a single string works fine when I'm reading the company in.

I know single SQL selects pretty well. But I've got very little experience with stored procedures (aside from calling them) and so what I'm asking here may be basic. If so, sorry. And again, this is for Sql Azure.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure, then you application should be able to parse XML.

Write a stored procedure to join the three tables, select the data given an input like company id, and return an xml record containing information from all three.

Look at the following references.

FOR XML

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx

CREATE PROCEUDRE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

If you need more help, you need to post a simple schema with sample data.

USE MY EXAMPLE BELOW FOR SCHEMA + DATA

[sql select a field into 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122335/sql-select-a-field-into-2-columns/21122489#21122489)

1 - Without detailed information, not one will be able to help you.

2 - Try it on your own.  I can give you the answer but you will not learn anything.

Sincerely

John